# How to Insert/append into Table1 when difference found in Table2 with if else condition

Tags: mysql, oracle, algorithm, plsql, create-table

**Requirement:**

We have monthly run process, in which we create `Table1` and `Table2`.

**1.** Let say if we ran our process in Jan it creates `Table2`. Since Jan is first run we don't have Table1 created before. so, system should put everything from `Table2` into `Table1`.

**2.** Now let say if we ran our process in Feb it creates `Table2`. And our system should check if `Table1` exists. If yes and `(t2.Run_dt > t1.Insert_dt)` then pick all ID's from `Table2` which don't exists in `Table1` and insert/append those records into `Table1`.

**3.** Now let say if we re-ran our process in Feb again it creates `Table2`. And our system should check if Table1 exists if yes and `(t2.Run_dt = t1.Insert_dt)` then pick all ID's from `Table2` which doesn't exists in `Table1` and insert/append those records into `Table1`.

**4.** and so on...

I have these two tables;

```
Table1

 ID    Price   Insert_Dt
----- ------- -------------
 345   24.35   01-APR-2015

Table2

 ID    Price   Run_Date
----- ------- -------------
 345   24.35   01-MAY-2015
 678   15.35   01-MAY-2015
```

I want to write a query to update table1 on the below given logic.

1. If `Table1.Run_date >= Table2.Insert_Dt`
   and `Table2 - Table1 = records found`
   then insert new records into `Table1`
2. If `Table1.Run_date >= Table2.Insert_Dt`
   and `Table2-Table1 = no records found`
   then do nothing
3. else do nothing

---

```
DECLARE
  nCount NUMBER;
  mCount NUMBER;
BEGIN

  select count(*) into nCount from dba_tables where table_name = Table1;

  if ( (nCount>0)
       and ( (select max(a.Run_Date) from Table1 a)
                > (select max(b.Insert_Date) from Table2 b) )  )
  then
    create table difference as
    select * from Table2 c where c.ID not in(select d.ID  from Table2 d)

    select count(*) into mCount
      from dba_tables
     where table_name = 'difference';

    if (nCount > 0) then insert /*+ append */ into Table1
      select ID,Price,Run_Date
        from (select ID,Price,Insert_Date from difference);
    end
END;
```

Comment: Im confused between table1 and table2 because in there is no run_date on table1 instead insert_dt and on table2 there is no insert_dt instead run_date.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you described, but I have a couple of questions:

```
insert into table1
with max_run as (
  select id, max (insert_dt) as max_date
  from table1
  group by id
)
select
  t2.id, t2.price, t2.run_date
from
  table2 t2,
  max_run t1
where
  t2.id = t1.id (+) and
  -- (t1.id is null or t2.run_date >= t1.max_date) changed below, per edit
 (t1.id is null or t2.run_date > t1.max_date)
```

1. Are you sure you want a `>= insert_dt` and not a `> insert_dt`?  Having a `>=` means we keep inserting those records over and over, even though they are not really new
2. Did you want to insert new records or update existing records with the new info?  Your inquiry said you wanted to insert them, and I didn't see any update code in your snippet, so I kept that as-is

Comment: I don't see difference table in ur query. So, here is situation: suppose we ran this for first month and if we re-ran same code in same month that will make insert_dt = run_dt, since we are calculating difference of both table so, we only inserting difference record into first table. so, it wont duplicate records.

Comment: Hi Qasim. Your question is lilte bit confusing. Can you please elaborate the requirement in general not the code?

Comment: @Quasim0787, I didn't use a difference table or even PLSQL.  If I understand your problem correctly (which is possible I don't), you don't need either -- straight SQL will do.  Your comment does make me think, however, that my comment #1 is right -- you want a `>` rather than a `>=`.  I have modified accordingly.

Comment: I inserted brief requirements above.